Black and white insects on by Green chilli plant.. need help
Can you guys please help me in identifying these black and white insects. Are these mites and what should I do to get rid of them..


Neem Oil?   Its difficult to see the critters from your photo.  Can you take a close up?

Mites, white fly, etc. I cannot see much and there are so many types, but the solution is the same: spray the leaves with strong jet of water (but without damaging leaves), ev. rinse with your hands. Possibly some sunny location when you are doing it, will help to dry it quickly and make the environment uncomfortable for the parasites. You will need to do it for few times.
I find that keeping the plants outdoor will help to solve the problem (after the jet of water) but indoor (e.g. for winter) slowly the plants get such parasites.
There are various other solution: sticky sheets, but I find impractical and not so effective, or chemical products, which I find often impractical because there are always ripe fruits and most of products have some wait time. Note: also for organic products it is either such case (waiting time), or you need to rinse the plant (contact products which may not taste good), but in later case: why not just do only the jet of water cleaning?
Note: as far I know, such parasites will attack many plants, so check also nearby plants (where you may also use chemical products).

The image you provide is not very clear, as far as I can conclude the plant has undergone a Fungal attack, depicting powdery mildew. As its obvious symptom, the presence of white powder on the lower leaf.
To get rid of this, The methods are to get a ready-to-use spray fungicide that is sulfur-based or copper-based. You can also make some home remedies such as using neem oil solution, baking soda solution, or potassium bicarbonate which will stop its further spreading.
The way of making these solutions is to Firstly, take 5 ml neem oil and 2.5 ml soap in 1 L of water mix them well, and spray on foliage
Secondly, take 1 teaspoon of baking soda add a few drops of liquid soap in 1 liter of water, and then spray it.
Third, Take 1 teaspoon potassium bicarbonate with Spray Potassium bicarbonate ½ tablespoon liquid soap in 1 gallon of water mix it well, and spray on foliage.
These are the 3 alternative options that you can choose on your own accord, select a suitable method spray it on the plant, and leave it for 3-4 hours after that rinse it off with water.

The asker describes insects and I see no sign of powdery mildew.

Yes it's not powder just insects and the leaf had turned yellow where they are situated
